# How do I create an SQLite 3 database handler for my Python logger?

Tags: python, sqlite, logging, python-logging

I have been trying to create a database handler for my logger with the built-in logging library in Python. I tried to do so by subclassing the main logging module's '`Handler`' class but it is throwing many errors, when the `StreamHandler` class is perfectly fine, and it was written just like how my `DatabaseHandler` class was written.

I have checked the documentation for the logging library and there appears to be no class for creating custom logging handlers. So, I decided to write the `DatabaseHandler` class without inheriting attributes from the `Handler` class and the SQLite 3 code threw an error saying that there is no such table as the `'logs'` table when I put in the first line to create that table if it didn't exist.

My code:

```
from logging import getLogger, StreamHandler, Formatter, Handler, NOTSET, getLevelName
from datetime import datetime as date_time
from sqlite3 import connect

class DatabaseHandler(Handler):
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.db_file = db_file
        self.db_file = connect(self.db_file)
    def emit(self, record):
            """
            Conditionally emit the specified logging record.
    
            Emission depends on filters which may have been added to the handler.
            Wrap the actual emission of the record with acquisition/release of
            the I/O thread lock. Returns whether the filter passed the record for
            emission.
            """
            self.db_file.executescript(
                'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logs (date TEXT, '
                'time TEXT, lvl INTEGER, lvl_name TEXT, msg TEXT, '
                'logger TEXT, lineno INTEGER);'
                'INSERT INTO logs VALUES ("%s", "%s", %s, "%s", "%s", "%s", %s)' % (
                    date_time.now().strftime('%A, the %d of %B, %Y'),
                    date_time.now().strftime('%I:%M %p'),
                    record.levelno,
                    record.level,
                    record.msg,
                    record.name,
                    record.lineno
                    )
            )
            self.db_file.commit()
            self.db_file.close()

logger = getLogger(__name__)

logger_formatter = Formatter(
    fmt = '<LVL: %(levelno)s (%(levelname)s), LOGGER: %(name)s> - "%(message)s at %(asctime)s"',
    datefmt = '%I:%M %p on %A, the %d of %B, %Y'
)

logger_stream_handler = StreamHandler()

logger_stream_handler.setFormatter(logger_formatter)
logger_stream_handler.setLevel(10)
logger_database_handler = DatabaseHandler('test.db')

logger.addHandler(logger_stream_handler)
logger.addHandler(logger_database_handler)

logger.log(
    msg = 'Something happened',
    level = 10
)

print(connect('test.db').execute('SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = "table"').fetchall())
```

The idea of how it will work is that it will be added as a handler for the logger and then everytime something is logged and a `LogRecord` is created, then it will also store the details of the `LogRecord` in the database's `logs` table.

I have also created an '`emit`' method for the class as that's what I believe is the method that the `Handler` class in the logging `__init__.py` module file triggers when a new logging call is made and a `LogRecord` is created.

But, here's the problem: Whenever I call `super().__init__(self)` on the class' `__init__` method to inherit the attributes from the `Handler` class, it throws this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 47, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 7, in _init_
  File"/lib/python3.8/logging/_init_.py", line 865, in _init_
     self.level = checkLevel(level) 
  File "/lib/python3.8/logging/__init_.py", line 192, in checkLevel
     elif str(level) == level:
  File "/lib/python3.8/logging/__init_.py", line 1035, in _repr_
     level = getLevelName(self.level)
AttributeError: 'DatabaseHandler' object has no attribute 'level'

[Program finished]

[Program finished]
```

Comment: Subclassing `Handler` is the correct approach to create custom handlers. What errors are you getting? Also you definitely should call `super.__init__` because otherwise your handler won't even have a `level` property.

Comment: @blues I get an error saying `AttributeError: 'DatabaseHandler' object has no attribute 'level'` whenever I do that. Also, I created an `emit` method for the class as that's what I saw the `Handler` class have in the logging `__init__.py` module file, and I think that is the method that is called when a new log call is created and a `LogRecord` is created.

Comment: The AttributeError should be fixed by the super init call. The `Handler` class init has this line: [`self.level = _checkLevel(level)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L864) Implementing `emit` is indeed the correct thing.

Comment: @blues
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 47, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 7, in \__init__
  File "/lib/python3.8/logging/\__init__.py", line 865, in \__init__
    self.level = _checkLevel(level)
  File "/lib/python3.8/logging/\__init__.py", line 192, in _checkLevel
    elif str(level) == level:
  File "/lib/python3.8/logging/\__init__.py", line 1035, in \__repr__
    level = getLevelName(self.level)
AttributeError: 'DatabaseHandler' object has no attribute 'level'

[Program finished]
```

Comment: @blues run the code yourself if you don't believe me

Comment: Since the stacktrace definitely says you're using Python 3, you shouldn't pass `self` to `super().__init__()`. Look at the stack trace! The `super` initializer is trying to convert your argument (your `DatabaseHandler` instance) into a level string and the handler's `__repr__` method is trying to access the `level` property which doesn't exist yet....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, you were not that far...

The error in calling `__init__` is caused by passing `self` which is interpreted as a **level**. And even if it is not a true error, creating a table is a Data Definition Language operation and should not be repeated on each message: it should go in the `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self, db_file):
    super().__init__()
    self.db_file = db_file
    self.db_file = connect(self.db_file)
    self.db_file.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logs (date TEXT, '
            'time TEXT, lvl INTEGER, lvl_name TEXT, msg TEXT, '
            'logger TEXT, lineno INTEGER)')
```

Later in `emit` you pass a `record.level` parameter which should be `record.levelname`. And you should not close the database in the emit method: a logger should be able to log more than one message! Furthermore, you are injecting the parameters in the query itself which is bad because it has been the cause of SQL injection attacks for decades. You should use a parameterized query:

```
        self.db_file.execute(
            'INSERT INTO logs VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4, :5, :6, :7)', (
                date_time.now().strftime('%A, the %d of %B, %Y'),
                date_time.now().strftime('%I:%M %p'),
                record.levelno,
                record.levelname,
                record.msg,
                record.name,
                record.lineno
                )
        )
        self.db_file.commit()
```

And as the default level is NOTSET you should set it on both the logger and its handler:

```
logger = getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(10)

logger_database_handler = DatabaseHandler('test.db')

logger.addHandler(logger_database_handler)
logger_database_handler.setLevel(10)

logger.log(
    msg = 'Something happened',
    level = 10
)
```

After those changes you should find the record content in the `logs` table...

Comment: Thank you so much, I lost hope thinking that no one would want to answer my question. Also, the reason why I injected the parameters in the SQLite query itself is because I was using the `executescript` SQLite 3 `Connection` method, which unfortunately does not support parameter substitution.